querySourceFeatures Not Returning All Features Within the Viewport
I’m encountering an issue where querySourceFeatures is not returning all the features that should be present within the viewport.
Details:

Vector Source: In my vector, there are a total of 1,524,444 features.
When using querySourceFeatures, I’m only able to retrieve 186,317 features, which is significantly less than expected.
I’ve also tried using queryRenderedFeatures, but I am seeing the same result.

Code Snippet:
map.querySourceFeatures('households', {
    sourceLayer: 'households'
});

Steps Taken:

I have confirmed that the data source contains the expected number of features.
The issue persists with queryRenderedFeatures as well, which makes me believe it’s related to how features are being queried or rendered.

Expected Behavior:
I expect to be able to query all 1,524,444 features within the viewport using querySourceFeatures or queryRenderedFeatures.
Environment:

Mapbox version: v3.6.0
Browser: Chrome 129.0.6668.58
OS:  macOS 15

Could anyone please help identify how to retrieve all the features using querySourceFeatures or guide me on what could be causing this limitation? Thanks!
